# Non-Example of covering space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X:= \mathbb{R_1} \sqcup \mathbb{R_2}$ where $\sqcup$ means the disjoint union.
Now $X$ is a topological space with the "Disjoint topology", in which the opens are disjoint union of opens of $\mathbb{R_1}$ and of $\mathbb{R_2}$.

I have the projection $\pi:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I can take the induced topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (the opens are the ones with pre-image an open of $X$).

Now $\pi$ is not a covering for $\mathbb{R} $.

I don't know precisely how to show this, my intuition is that if I can take an open interval $I \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\pi^{-1}(I)$ will be connected in $X$ but not arc connected and so there is no omeomorphism between the "components" of the pre-image of $I$ and $I$.

Am I right?

Comment: by the projection, do you mean take $(x, i ) \in \mathbb{R}_1 \sqcup \mathbb{R}_2$ to $x$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R_1} \sqcup \mathbb{R_2}$ with the obvious topology--the finest one that makes the injections $x_i\mapsto (x_i,i)$ continuous-- is a coproduct, not a product so it's not clear what you mean by "component".

Comment: I'm not confident with that topology, so I think at the space $X$ like $\mathbb{R}$ counted two times, or like $\{ \mathbb{R} \times \{0 \} \}  \cup \{ \mathbb{R} \times \{ 1 \} \} $ So the pre-image of $I$ will be of the form $J:=J_1 \cup J_2$ where $J_1 \in \{ \mathbb{R} \times \{0 \} \}, J_2 \in \{ \mathbb{R} \times \{ 1 \} \}$ Now, $J$ is connected, but it is not arc connected. Is it right?

Comment: $J$ is certainly not connected, since it a disjoint union of two sets $J_1,J_2$ each of which is open in $\mathbb{R} \times \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Yes, it's true, so the function $\pi$ is actually a covering for $\mathbb{R}$ because both $J_1 , J_2$ are omeomorphic to $I$ via the restriction of $\pi$.